# INSERT INTO database from another database, specifying some values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I've researched about this but haven't found a particular solution for this case.
I have two tables, each one in a different databases.

Let's say they are `DB1.T1` and `DB2.T2`.

From `DB1.T1` I want to select all rows from two specific columns `ID` and `Description`.

`DB2.T2` has the same two columns but also three additional columns: `T2.ID`, `Enable`, `Date`.

Some considerations. DB2.T2 is a SQL Server, I've always worked with MySQL but this SQL Server had some inconsistencies from my previous experiences. The AUTOINCREMENT default condition didn't exist, and also the insert of default timestamp or date value when new record is created was not available.

From my research I've come to some kinda solution that would be

```
INSERT INTO DB2.T2(ID, Description, Enable, Code ,Date)
    SELECT ID, Description 
    FROM DB1.T1;
```

BUT how can I add the three remaining columns?

I was thinking to do some while loop and insert the increment as ID for DB2.T2 using the allowed `GETDATE()` function, but I'm not sure how to do it right away.

Can I use the previous syntax of select INTO and also use INSERT INTO to do something like this?

```
INSERT INTO DB2.T2(ID, Description, Enable, Code, Date) 
VALUES (index,?,1,?,GETDATE())
```

I'm really confused right now. I hope you can get what I'm trying to explain.

Beside exporting data from one table to another, I want to insert additional data to the remaining columns. For enable I want it to be always 1, and the date the current date, The ID has to be a number and must be incrementing according to the row.

What do you recommend to do?

Meanwhile I'll keep my self trying to find similar solutions to this problem.

Thanks in advance. :)

Additional data. I'm working by VPN on a remote connection, all I've got is some sort of the cmd interface to insert and work with the DB. There are like 20000 rows, and importing exporting by CSV using bulk seems pretty strange to me.

Comment: The both DB as in the same server? And the Server security option "Cross database ownership chining" is set to on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you could use:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.T2(ID, Description, Enable, Code ,Date) 
SELECT ID, Description, 1 ,null,getdate() FROM DB1.T1;
```

When you start to think about looping, stop and revisit the problem. Almost always a better way.

If ID should be incrementing and not based on what is in DB1.T1, look into making that column in DB2 [IDENTITY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property). If you do, then you would just leave the ID off of the insert, and SQL Server will handle that itself.

Comment: Well yes, this is exactly what I thought it could be but I wasn't sure it could be done. I'll try right away and inform you if it was possible. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank a lot!